# How to bind C-x SPC locally to gud mode in Emacs 25

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, gud

Similar to [How to change GUD breakpoint keybinding to the old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394456/how-to-change-gud-breakpoint-keybinding-to-the-old-one) but I would like to bind <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to be `gud-break`.

What I have working (well it is a hack; keep reading) is:

```
  (define-key ctl-x-map " " 'gud-break)
```

but `ctl-x-map` is a global variable akin to the global map.  And in fact, if I switch to another C++ buffer and type C-h k C-x SPC I get:

```
C-x SPC runs the command gud-break (found in global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function.

It is bound to C-x SPC, C-x C-a C-b.

(gud-break ARG)

Set breakpoint at current line.
```

which means the global definition across all buffers is what was changed, which is not correct AFAIK.

Is there a way to "insert" or somehow affect the local key map for C-x, which I believe is `gud-mode-map`, because I want that binding to not be global for all C++ buffers.  E.g., the global binding for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is `rectangle-mark-mode`.

Yes I realize the standard binding is `C-x C-a C-b` for `gud-break`, but that is asking for RSI.

### Update #1

Since I need the local key map for `gud-mode-map`, this needs to be active only when I'm running a debugger. In my case, this is in C++ mode buffers, but my understanding is that `gud-mode-map` becomes active in those C++ mode buffers only during the debug session, and is removed from the key bindings when gud mode is finished.

### Update #2

This did not work:

```
(define-key gud-mode-map [(control x ?\ )] 'gud-break) ;; <-- gave "Two bases given in one event" error too.
(define-key gud-mode-map (kbd "C-x SPC") 'gud-break) ;; <-- this does not work either.
```

### Update #3

As an experiment, I commented out my `define-key` bindings in my hook I add to `gud-gdb-mode-hook`, reran gdb, then switched to the gud buffer (not the C++ source file) and typed `C-h k C-x SPC` I get this:

```
C-x SPC runs the command gud-break (found in gud-mode-map), which is
an interactive Lisp closure.

It is bound to <menu-bar> <debug> <break>, C-x SPC, C-c C-b, C-x C-a
C-b.

(gud-break ARG)

Set breakpoint at current line.
```

But then when I switch over to the C++ buffer that should *also* have the same bindings inserted temporarily (while gud mode is active), and then do the same thing I get this instead:

```
C-x SPC runs the command rectangle-mark-mode (found in global-map),
which is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
'rect.el'.

It is bound to C-x SPC.

(rectangle-mark-mode &optional ARG)

Toggle the region as rectangular.
Activates the region if needed.  Only lasts until the region is deactivated.
```

Switching back to the gud buffer, and typing `C-h m` shows this:

```
Debugger mode defined in 'gud.el':
Major mode for interacting with an inferior debugger process.

   You start it up with one of the commands M-x gdb, M-x sdb, M-x dbx,
M-x perldb, M-x xdb, or M-x jdb.  Each entry point finishes by executing a
hook; 'gdb-mode-hook', 'sdb-mode-hook', 'dbx-mode-hook',
'perldb-mode-hook', 'xdb-mode-hook', or 'jdb-mode-hook' respectively.

After startup, the following commands are available in both the GUD
interaction buffer and any source buffer GUD visits due to a breakpoint stop
or step operation:

C-x SPC sets a breakpoint at the current file and line.  In the
GUD buffer, the current file and line are those of the last breakpoint or
step.  In a source buffer, they are the buffer's file and current line.

...
```

Notice the reference to `C-x SPC` above. It is as if they intended to bind `C-x SPC` but it did not work, or something is preventing it from being bound properly in that buffer when gud mode is entered.

Comment: You say you want the binding to be local but you don't say local to what.  IOW, in which buffers would you want `C-x SPC` to call `gud-break`?

Comment: @Stefan I just updated the end of the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've chosen to give up on this altogether. using `C-x SPC` in the buffer is problematic anyhow. I noticed that the `C-x C-a` prefix that is used for the gud bindings are left in the C++ buffer even after gud finishes, so the gud mode is not cleaning up after itself anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *exactly* clear on what you want. But if you only want to redefine the key `C-x SPC` when the `gud-mode-map` is active, then tell `define-key` you want to use that map: `(define-key gud-mode-map ...)`.

Comment: Thanks and you are on the right track, but that did not work for me. See Update #2 inside my description for what I've tried. Perhaps my `(kbd...)` needs adjustment?

Comment: @bgoodr After having done `(define-key gud-mode-map (kbd "C-x SPC") 'gud-break)` and are in `gud-mode`, what does `C-h C-x SPC RET` show?

Comment: `C-h C-x SPC` is not what I think you meant because doing so gives `C-h C-x SPC` is undefined. I suspect what you meant was `C-h k C-x SPC` to use `C-h k` (for `describe-key`) and then type `C-x SPC`. So I did that and got `C-x SPC runs the command rectangle-mark-mode`. I did that from within a C++ buffer under gud-mode.

Comment: But this is strange. Shouldn't `describe-mode` show something about the gud mode being somehow "active"? I'm not seeing any reference to anything with "gud" in it in the Help buffer that results.

Comment: Added Update #3 to main description in hopes it will help solve this puzzle. I'm still baffled.

Comment: Giving up and answering my own question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50979549/257924. But if anyone has any simple solutions to avoiding the `C-x C-a` prefix that would be good, but I doubt it is possible at least not cleanly for all bindings for gud mode.